# Avoiding conflicts in git when merging a squashed commit from main into feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-merge-conflict, git-squash

Consider the following practice:

- A developer branches from `main` and creates as many commits as needed in a feature branch
- Once the feature is completed, all commits are squashed and merged into the `main` branch (for instance, think of a GitHub's "Squash and merge" button)

And now this is a use case that interests me:

1. Create and work on a `feature1` branch
2. Create a `feature2` branch starting from the last commit of the `feature1` branch (see the `C` commit in the image below)
3. Squash and merge `feature1` into `main` (see the commit `G`)
4. Merge this newly created commit `G` into the `feature2` branch
5. Continue working on the `feature2` branch

In other words, the merge of `G` into the `feature2` branch in step 4 looks like this:

```
user@host:~/repo (main)$ git checkout feature2
user@host:~/repo (feature2)$ git merge main     # merge G into feature2
```

[image: merge conflicts after squash and merge]

Often, this merge (see the commit `H`) results in a number of merge conflicts.

How to completely eliminate these conflicts?

The easiest solution I can think of is the following (see the image below):

```
user@host:~/repo (main)$ git checkout feature1
user@host:~/repo (feature1)$ git merge main         # merge G into feature1; essentially, an empty commit
user@host:~/repo (feature1)$ git checkout feature2
user@host:~/repo (feature2)$ git merge feature1     # merge G' into feature2
```

[image: overcoming merge conflicts after squash and merge]

To put it another way, instead of merging `G` into `feature2` directly, we first merge `G` into `feature1` and then merge `feature1` into `feature2`.

Is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rebase `feature2` onto `main` just after that `feature1` has been squashed and merged.

Something like:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto main C feature2
```

This will rebase commits from `C` (exclusive) to `feature2` (inclusive) on top of `main`.

So instead of merging main into feature2(red), feature2 moves to be on top of main(green).
[image]

However I'm not sure it qualifies as simpler. And one drawback is that you will get commits of `main` in the resulting branch (but that's what you want ultimately I guess).

*Personal opinion: do not use squash in the first place if the branch is used by other people as reference.*

Comment: I could easily imagine the `feature1` branch being deleted after it is merged to main, so we may no longer have easy access to it.  This argues for rebasing being a good option.

Comment: Yeah, good simple option. One potential drawback: if `feature2` has been already pushed upstream, we would need to `--force` after this rebase.